# Quartz display services replacement for deprecated functions?

Tags: c++, macos, quartz-graphics

The [Quartz display services reference manual](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html) lists several functions as deprecated, (for example `CGDisplayCurrentMode`), but doesn't mention what the replacement function is.

What should I be using to find information about the current video mode?

Is there a way to find out this kind of information? The reference manual on the apple developer site seems very hard to navigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode() looks like the replacement. It is new in 10.6.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/ApplicationServicesRefUpdate/Articles/ApplicationServices_10.5-10.6_SymbolChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009185-SW41

Comment: Just Google for CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode.